# Psycopg2 adapter installation on Mountain Lion

Tags: psycopg2, postgresql-9.2

I am a beginner trying to learn django. I wanted to install Postgresql.

```
Anurags-MacBook-Pro:psycopg2-2.4.6 anurag_prasad$ python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090104 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o
unable to execute clang: No such file or directory
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the [Xcode Command Line Tools](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Command%20Line%20Tools) so that the `clang` compiler is available to compile the native portion of the pyscopg2 module.

Comment: It worked but I got the following error:
error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/psycopg2': Permission denied

Comment: `sudo python setup.py install`